# node | MySQL multiple WHERE with AND clause

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to do a statement in node using mysql package. I am trying to select from a table `WHERE` with a `AND` clause such as `WHERE id = 1 AND course = 1` so far I've got as far as being able to SELECT but I'm getting an error, I can see the error though and it's that there is no `AND` when I am binding the id.

This is my current code.

```
let sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE ?';

let values = {
    id: 1,
    course: 1
}

database.query(sql, values, (err, result) => {

}
```

This is the error I am getting...

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1, course = 1`

The query once it has been through node is missing the `AND`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

probably should look smth like this:

```
let sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? AND course = ?';

database.query(sql, [1, 1], (err, result) => {

}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/shownodejs_cmd.asp?filename=demo_db_where_placeholders

Answer (score 1):

I am defining a generic way of reforming a simple sql into parameterized query.

Let's say the given sql is:

```
var sql = "SELECT LK_USER_ID, LK_USER_STATUS, LK_USER_CONATCT_OFF FROM lk_users WHERE LK_USER_FNAME = 'test' AND LK_USER_LOGIN = 'debsnew' ORDER BY LK_USER_ID DESC LIMIT 1, 5";
```

Now the parameterized query string version of the above query is:

```
var sql = 'SELECT ?? FROM ?? WHERE LK_USER_FNAME = ? AND LK_USER_LOGIN = ? ORDER BY ?? DESC LIMIT ?,?';
var columns = ['LK_USER_ID', 'LK_USER_STATUS', 'LK_USER_CONATCT_OFF'];
var tbl = TABLE_PREFIX +'user';
var query = mysql.conn.query(sql, [columns, tbl, 'test', 'debsnew', 'LK_USER_ID',  0, 5], (err, results, fileds) => {
    console.log(results);
    res.json({'status': 1, 'data': results});
});
```

You can console log the generated sql as:

```
console.log(query.sql);
```

In your case the sql is:

```
let sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1 AND course = 1';
```

The reformed parameterized query version is:

```
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE id = ? AND course = ?';
var tbl = 'users';
var query = mysql.conn.query(sql, [tbl, 1, 1], (err, results, fileds) => {
    console.log(results);
    res.json({'status': 1, 'data': results});
});
```

You can match the generated sql with the original one through

```
console.log(query.sql);
```